# android how to bring our application to foreground when it goes to background?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to bring my application to foreground when it goes to background.
when my application is in the foreground(Moving  background to **foreground** **after** a **long period of time**) then the app raise an exception I couldn't find the Exception(App isn't working properly). How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: onResume() I have written a function to call Web Api after getting the result from the Web Api then populate the value to the screen. when my app  moving background to foreground after a long period of time then the app raise an exception.